# How to get project list from each site and then workbook list from each project?

Tags: python, tableau-api

First I want list of sites then next I want list of projects inside each site and then I want list of workbook in each project.

i.e sites>>projects>>workbooks.

I am using Tableauserverclient. Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Tableau's [github](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref) page. It has all the examples.

I would consider using Tableau's [workgroup](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/perf_collect_server_repo.htm) database though unless you are requiring python for some other action.

**Sites**

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC  
tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')  
server = TSC.Server('https://SERVER')  

# query the sites
all_sites, pagination_item = server.sites.get()

# print all the site names and ids
for site in all_sites:
   print(site.id, site.name, site.content_url, site.state)
```

**Projects**

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC  
tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', site_id='CONTENTURL')  
server = TSC.Server('https://SERVER')  

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth): 
    # get all projects on site
    all_project_items, pagination_item = server.projects.get()
    print([proj.name for proj in all_project_items])
```

**Workbooks**

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC
tableau_auth = TSC.TableauAuth('username', 'password', site_id='site')
server = TSC.Server('https://servername')

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):
    all_workbooks_items, pagination_item = server.workbooks.get()
    # print names of first 100 workbooks
    print([workbook.name for workbook in all_workbooks_items])
```

Comment: When i am trying to get project list using site.id , i am getting sign in error why?

Comment: can we do sign in using site.id in place of site.name in TSC.TableauAuth()

Comment: The Site portion will run without defining the site_id. I've edited the answer to reflect.

Comment: **we can get the projects list of particular site** 
pass site_id=site.content_url in tableauauth method